# C# & VB6: How to convert 'with' statement to C#?

Tags: c#, vb6

How can I convert this piece of VB6 code into C#?

http://pastebin.com/f16e19351

I've tried on my own and got so far to:

http://pastebin.com/f7ca199f0

EDIT: Code I'm trying to translate exists here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/MouseHunter.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# equivalent for Visual Basic keyword: 'With' ... 'End With'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174773/c-sharp-equivalent-for-visual-basic-keyword-with-end-with)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't shown the `EventThief` code, which makes it impossible to tell, really. But in general:

```
With expression
   .Foo = a
   .Bar = b
End With
```

would translate to

```
var x = expression;
x.Foo = a;
x.Bar = b;
```

(Of course you can specify the type explicitly...)

The commonality here is that `expression` is only evaluated once. In the particular code you showed, there's no need for an extra variable of course, as the expression is *only* the local variable in the first place.

Your actual error looks like it's just to do with the types of `EventThief.RIGHT_DOWN` etc rather than with the WITH statement.

EDIT: Okay, you've now shown the original EventThief code which *does* use Booleans... but you haven't shown your *ported* `EventThief` code. You wrote:

> It says et.LEFT_UP is a short

... but it shouldn't be. In the original it's a `Boolean`, so why is it a `short` in your port?

Comment: I added a link in my question, see the edit. Just search for "eventthief" and you'll find it.

Comment: I don't know why it's a short, I use tlbimp as mentioned here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/CSharpAndActiveXDlls.aspx to allow the ActiveX dll to be used in .NET and I take it that it converted it to a short instead or something? I'll just try and manually convert the whole thing to C#. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The following in VB

```
With EventStealingInfo
    .RIGHT_DOWN = True
    .RIGHT_UP = True
End With
```

can be roughly translated to

```
var EventStealingInfo = new EventThief(){
    RIGHT_DOWN = true,
    RIGHT_UP = true
};
```

where `RIGHT_UP` and `RIGHT_DOWN` are public properties in the `EventStealingInfo` class.

This construct in C# is known as [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Like so

```
With EventStealingInfo
    .RIGHT_DOWN = True
    .RIGHT_UP = True
End With
```

becomes

```
EventStealingInfo.RIGHT_DOWN = true;
EventStealingInfo.RIGHT_UP = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's closer you can go:

```
EventThief EventStealingInfo = new EventThief()
{
    RIGHT_DOWN = true,
    RIGHT_UP = true
};
```

Comment: I'd go with this answer (except that it should really say `... = new EventThief()`). Object initializers are probably the closest thing to Visual Basic's `With` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Can I call your proposal *Option A*.

1. Take community [VB6 code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/MouseHunter.aspx) that creates a DLL for dealing with Windows hooks.
2. Translate that to C#

Can I suggest Option B and Option C, which I think will be easier?

*Option B*
1. Start with [Microsoft's C# code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) for dealing with Windows hooks.
2. Adapt it as necessary, looking at what API calls the [VB6 code makes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/MouseHunter.aspx).

*Option C*
1. Take the built VB6 DLL from the [community code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/MouseHunter.aspx).
2. Call that DLL from your new C# application via [Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I tried option 2 first, then I tried option 3 when the first failed. That's when I ran into the error with the wrong type in the EventThief struct, so I tried option 1 and I ran into another error that said something about the GUID being wrong and I got lost on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to With in C# as far as I am aware and you need to explicitly list the object when referred to its member functions/properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no C# equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the type of the LEFT_UP to be a bool?

looking at your code and the way you are using the EventThief, you might want to use a flag enumeration so you can set individual bits and then do bitwise comparisons.

Comment: I'll have to look that up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "with" keyword is just a shortcut to save retyping the variable name when you're setting multiple properties.  There is no equivalent in C#.

Even if there were you would still have an issue that you're apparently trying to assign a boolean to a short data type.

What's in the EventThief class?  Can you simply make the LEFT_UP fields boolean instead?

Comment: Look at the link in the edit in my question, search for "EventThief" and you'll find it.

Comment: Actually it also caches the object reference, which can save time if the object in question must be resolved by chasing down a nested series of properties - or worse yet a method call that creates an instance for temporary use.  Of course you can also manually cache by creating a new temporary reference variable first and using that.