# C# equivalent for Visual Basic keyword: 'With' ... 'End With'?

Tags: c#, vb.net, language-design, with-statement

In Visual Basic, if you are going to change multiple properties of a single object, there's a `With/End With` statement:

```
Dim myObject as Object

// ' Rather than writing:
myObject.property1 = something
myObject.property2 = something2

// ' You can write:

with myObject
   .property1 = something
   .property2 = something2
   ...
End With
```

I know C# can do it when creating a new object:

```
Object myObject = new Object { property1 = something, property2 = something2, ...};
```

But how do I do that if `myOject` is already created (like what Visual Basic is doing)?

Comment: A few people are saying it's bad, but I'd like to point out that Microsoft's coding conventions for VB.NET says that you should use the `With` keyword when making a series of calls to one object - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With block equivalent in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481725/with-block-equivalent-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You cannot do this in C#.**

This feature is specific to VB and the closest you can come in C# is the object initializer like you describe.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
static class Extension
{
    public static void With<T>(this T obj, Action<T> a)
    {
        a(obj);
    }    
}

class Program
{
    class Obj
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
        public int Prop4 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var detailedName = new Obj();
        detailedName.With(o => {
            o.Prop1 = 1;
            o.Prop2 = 2;
            o.Prop3 = 3;
            o.Prop4 = 4;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make that an extension-method! Then you can do like `detailedName.With(o => { o.Prop1 = 4 })`

Comment: And btw. +1 for creativity :-)

Comment: Note: If you use Cadenza, chock full of nice .NET extensions, you get a method that has exactly this implementation: http://www.gitorious.org/cadenza/cadenza/blobs/master/src/Cadenza/Cadenza/ObjectCoda.cs#line173

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to avoid lots of typing you can give your object a shorter name:

```
var x = myObject;
x.property1 = something;
x.property2 = something2;
```

Comment: Yeah, and to take it a step farther you can even do `using(var x = myObject) {/*newline*/x.property1=something;}`

Comment: @Alxandr: Very bad idea, that will call `Dispose` at the end of the block (and won't even compile for types that don't implement `IDisposable`).

Comment: Oo. Good point. My bad. I just thought it disposed of the "x" variable, but that beeing a reference could be fatal :-P

Comment: If you want the variable to go out of scope when you are done you can just surround the code in curly braces to create a new scope.

Comment: Avoiding lots of typing, really? With the kickass intellisense we have?! It's all about readability imo.

Answer (score 3):

> **Why doesn't C# have VB.NET's 'with' operator?**
>
> Many people, including the C# language designers, believe that 'with' often harms readability, and is more of a curse than a blessing. It is clearer to declare a local variable with a meaningful  name, and use that variable to perform multiple operations on a single object, than it is to have a block with a sort of implicit context.
>
> by [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: ...And other people believe that VB's "with" statement is a useful feature which offers some semantics that are not as conveniently achieved via other means.

Comment: Interesting that they call the syntax a curse and then nearly replicate it in object initialization syntax...

Comment: This is one thing that's really missing from C#.  The With statement makes things a lot cleaner when setting multiple properties on an existing object.  If it's so bad why bring it into C# when creating a new object?

Answer (score 2):

[@Mark Byers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4174790/168941) is good but the variable `x` will live after properties are set. And you can't use name `x` again (in same block).

Try this (*And object must be reference type in this sample*) :

```
void Main()
{
    var myObject1 = new Foo();
    var myObject2 = new Hoo();

    //elided...

    {
        var _ = myObject1;
        _.MyPropertyA = 2;
        _.MyPropertyB = "3";
    }

    {
        var _ = myObject2;
        _.MyPropertyX = 5;
        _.MyPropertyY = "asd";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET includes some of VB6's design flaws for the sake of backward compatibility. While Javascript has the same design flaw (indeed an even worse one, as its `with` leads to more ambiguous constructs), most other C-syntax languages don't, so there's no backward-compatibility benefit in adding it to C#.

Comment: Actually there is a distinct advantage to having `with` in JavaScript. It allows you to introduce a new scope to your functions!

Comment: The "With" statement in VB, when used with structures, offers semantics that are not conveniently available in C.  Given that VB's "With" uses a leading period to avoid ambiguity, I'm not sure why you regard it as a design flaw?

Answer (score 0):

If the "with" expression is a class type, the "With" statement is equivalent to creating a new temporary variable of that type, initialized to the "With" expression, and preceding each leading "." with that variable.  If it is a structure type, however, things are more complicated.  Consider the code (obviously not the way one would normally write something, but written as it is to make a point:

```
  With MyPoints(N) ' Array of Point
    N=SomeNewValue
    .X = MyPoints(N).X
    .Y = MyPoints(N).Y
  End With
```

The "With" statement effectively latches a reference to MyPoints(N).  Even if MyPoints is changed to some other array, or N is changed, the latched reference will still point to the same element of the same array as it did when the With statement was executed.  If one declared a local variable P of type Point and grabbed MyPoints(N), and then write to P.X and P.Y, the writes would only hit the local copy P, rather than updating the array.  To achieve similar semantics in C#, one would have to either use local variables to hold both MyPoints and N, or else place the contents of the With statement within an anonymous function which has a ref parameter of type Point.  To avoid having to create a closure at run-time, the anonymous function should also accept, probably by reference, any local variables it will need from the outer scope.