# Any Visual Basic 'With' analog in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, vb.net-to-c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# equivalent for Visual Basic keyword: 'With' ... 'End With'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174773)

#### VB.NET

```
With Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta
    a = .ZetaPropertyA
    b = .ZetaPropertyB
    c = .ZetaPropertyC
End With
```

#### C#?

```
a = Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta.ZetaPropertyA
b = Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta.ZetaPropertyB  
c = Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta.ZetaPropertyC
```

Comment: no, using is for classes implementing `IDisposeable`.

Comment: I can smell `Alpa.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta.ZetaPropertyA` a mile off. There's probably something wrong with your architecture if you're having to reach across this many relationships to set a property.

Comment: spender: OR Mapper with a tree like structure of objects.

Comment: @spender - This is called Law of Demeter:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: @spender: `GlobalProperties.Application.User.CurrentUser.TextOptions.WelcomeFontColor`

Comment: Just a comment on style, I used to really like the `With` construct in VB but a few years ago I decided that I didn’t like it any more. So now I use a local variable as a shorthand, even in VB in preference of a `With` block.

Comment: Just because VB jumped off a bridge, doesn't mean C# has to too ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, doesn't exist.

Though you could shorten it a bit:

```
var z = Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta;

z.ZetaPropertyA = a;
z.ZetaPropertyB = b; 
z.ZetaPropertyC = c;
```

for your other case:

```
var z = Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta;

a = z.ZetaPropertyA;
b = z.ZetaPropertyB;
c = z.ZetaPropertyC;
```

That should've been obvious though ;)

Comment: I thought this was a pretty good workaround...  Not perfect, but only one extra character per line.  And I always thought the WITH statement was less readable for a maintenance programmer anyway.

Comment: +1 Nice workaround. You beat me to the punch. And i agree with David: "with" is ugly and seems to obfuscate rather than help!

Comment: nothing obfuscates like `$$var` in php.

Comment: It may be 1 extra character per line (or 2 if you count the semi-colon), as David pointed out, but then you also don't have to have the "End With".  Just thought I'd point that out, in case anyone is counting characters.

Answer (score 3):

For new instances you can use object initializer:

```
Alpa.Beta.Gama.Eta = new Zeta
{
    ZetaPropertyA = a, 
    ZetaPropertyB = b,
    ZetaPropertyC = c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing like the `with` construct in C#.

Answer (score 1):

[Nope](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121124450/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/11/why-doesn-t-c-have-vb-net-s-with-operator.aspx).  The workaround is a (short) local variable name instead of `with`.  Adds a few characters per line, but you still end up with fully qualified references.

Comment: The code update doesn't change anything.  You can still declare a `var` to everything except `ZetaXXX` and do as said.

Comment: If a "With" expression is of a class type, the effect is analogous to using a local variable with a short name.  If the expression is a mutable structure, however, there is no direct equivalent.  Matching the semantics of "With MyPoints(I,J) : MyPoints = SomeOtherArray : I=someOtherValue : J=someOtherValue : .X=5 : .Y=9 : End With" would require making local copies of MyPoints, I, and J, or using some other trick to get the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, C# doesn't have that. The object initializer @Jakub suggests might provide an alternative, or:

If you design `Zeta` yourself, you could use the **[fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)** design pattern. That would allow you to do:

```
Alpha.Beta.Gama.Eta.Zeta
    .SetPropertyA(A)
    .SetPropertyB(B)
    .SetPropertyC(C);
```

Which comes close to what you want, at the expense of a lot of work elsewhere. And remember that a fluent interface is not always the best design choice.